# cURL multipart/form-data with files to Python request

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests

Am struggling to translate a working cURL command into an equivalent Python request. The cURL command is as follows:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:3001/api/v1/document \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@/home/user1/test.pdf;type=application/pdf' \
  -F 'config=@config.json;type=application/json'
```

Am using Python 3.6 and the `request` library and have been considering various approaches. One of those, which IMHO should work, but gives a **Error: Multipart: Boundary not found** error on the server is the following:

```
url = 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/document'
headers  = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
file = "/home/user1/test.pdf"

files = {
     'file': (file, open(file, 'rb'),'type=application/pdf'),
      'config': ('config.json',open('config.json','rb'),'type=application/json')
 } 

r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers )
```

I have looked at various online "translaters", including https://curl.trillworks.com/ but none of them give a working answer. Also tried a number of variations, which I found in other posts, such as removing the `content-type` in the header, or using `json.dump()` instead of the `open()` function, but still, no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try removing the headers 'multipart/form-data' is already set when you use `files` and add the boundary too

Comment: also the `type=` is unnecessary I think

Comment: When I remove the header, I get an 415, Unsupported Media error. Also, how do I set the boundary?

Comment: type=application/pdf should be  application/pdf and type=application/json just application/json

Comment: Thank you Bertrand. That solved the problem. I needed to do both, remove the headers as well as remove "type=" from the pdf and json file for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Bertrand Martel did the trick in the end:

1. Removing `headers`
2. Removing `'type='` from both, the pdf and json files.

The working solution looks thus as follows:

```
url = 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/document'

file = "/home/user1/test.pdf"

files = {
     'file': (file, open(file, 'rb'),'application/pdf'),
      'config': ('config.json',open('config.json','rb'),'application/json')
 } 

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```